# Laravel 5.8 with Bootstrap 3

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, package.json, npm-run

I have a problem to downgrade Bootstrap version in Laravel. Laravel comes with Bootstrap 4 but I want to use Bootstrap 3. So I change the version in package.json and run npm install. But if I run npm run dev from package.json it throws an error because of missing file bootstrap/scss/bootstrap. Also B3 comes with Less instead of scss. So I am little confused what and how should be configured to work with Bootstrap 3 and Less. Hope that is all and it will work after the fix.

Here is the issue file in resources/sass/app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

and here is package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use Bootstrap3's less files, at least a `less` compiler for node. Make `app.scss` a `.less` file to compile. Make changes in `webpack.mix.js`. Not worth the hassle imho, stick with BS4

Comment: Yes hassle thats what makes this feature. Somebody knows what is the best for others.

Comment: "_Somebody knows what is the best for others_" Didn't say that, I explicitly said that was my opinion. Reading the Bootstrap3 documentation, there's an official Sass port https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#sass you could try. Good luck

Comment: Yes you did not. I say it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it old-school style. Hardcode it in your html template:

1.Insert

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-RTQy8VOmNlT6b2PIRur37p6JEBZUE7o8wPgMvu18MC4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

2.In **resources/js/app.js** file, delete **require('./bootstrap')**

3.Don't import bootstrap in your **app.scss** file.

You can still compile anything required inside your **app.js** and **app.scss**